# Efficiently copying vectors in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Efficiently copying vectors in C++11?

Is it automatically done by the compiler when you say:

```
v1 = v2;
```

where v1 and v2 are std::vector.

Or should I use memcpy or else? I am talking about big vectors here,
we have like 10000 elements in one.

Comment: Yes, that is done as efficiently as possible. Also note that you are using the assignment operator which is not equal to copying.

Comment: So there is no need to think low level then about using functions like memcpy? Cool!

Comment: Using `memcpy` would even be wrong for non-POD items.

Comment: I think the way you suggested is the most efficient and easy (and so also the best) way.

Comment: @bamboon: It's called "the copy assignment operator"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the most effective, correct and efficient method to copy a vector's contents into an existing vector.

All elements are copied fully and properly using the RAII idiom, and the allocation of backing memory should be as fast as possible since the new container size is known up-front.